# using x-jquery-tmpl variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I'm using the jQuery file upload plugin, there is script by `type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"`. I see this type of script for the first time but however I got how it works (at least the ones used in this script). there are some return values in this script like _name (that is used like `${_name}` and I think it must be something like document.write, right?) I need to save this `_name` value in localStorage. how can I read this value in javascript?

Comment: `console.log(_name);`

Comment: This is jQuery template, not really a script. Take a look here: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx

Comment: now imagine will _name be valid outsite the script? because I have to open another script tag with type=javascript, I don't think it will work there

Comment: well now how do I get the value of this in javascript?